# rethinkdb password for user from Node.js

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have successfully configured a user "bob" to use the password "secret" in rethinkdb:

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('users').insert({id: 'bob', password: 'secret'})
```

From Node.js, I'm trying to connect to it using npm's rethinkdb module.

```
r.connect({ host: 'backend', port: 28015, db: 'db', user: 'bob', password: 'secret' });
```

I get the following error regarding the password:

> Unhandled rejection ReqlAuthError: Wrong password

Without a password on rethinkdb, the connection succeeds, so there is no connectivity issue. With a different username, I get the expected "unknown user" error... do I get a hash for the password when I create it on rethinkdb? Any idea?

Comment: hi, i have same problem and it isn't clear how you resolved it from the comments. can you elaborate how you fixed it.
All i want is able to connect with user 'bob' and password 'secret'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rethinkDB docs.

> password: the password for the user account to connect as (default "",
>   empty).
>
> **Important**: You can update a password of a user after you *connect* to the database.

You can remove a password with the line of code, by using `update` methoed and setting the password to `false` value.

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('users').get('bob').update({password: false})
```

You can change a password of a user by using `insert` method. Here is an example.

```
r.db('rethinkdb').table('users').insert({id: 'bob', password: 'secret'})
```

Comment: The password has been set succesfully from Rethinkdb's administration console. The problem is how I connect to it from Node.js.

Comment: hmm so the problem states itself, you can't set the password right, if you could, it still wouldn't have been empty @dgulabs let me check on solutions for it

Comment: so you can connect to the db with this command : `r.connect({ host: 'backend', port: 28015, db: 'db', user: 'bob' });` am I right? Have you tried to run the `insert` function after you have connected? so `insert` should come after `connect`

Comment: I cannot connect without a password, given that the user is successfully inserted with a password (the insert() from the administration console works successfully and indicates that 'bob' has a password). The problem is that 'secret' doesn't seem to be a valid password...

Comment: interesting, so the password value does not work... after you have created the user try to update the password by using this then, `r.db('rethinkdb').table('users').get('bob').update({password: "myPassword"})`

Comment: and then run it again @dgulabs

Comment: what have you gotten? @dgulabs

Comment: Ok, it seems to work if I don't have a password for the admin account (specified through --initial-password for rethinkdb). If the admin account has no password, I can use my custom user. Weird.

Comment: are you having the same problem with admin account? has your problem been solved?

Comment: It's fixed, but if I set a password for the admin account, a non-admin user cannot login. But I consider it fixed for my current case. Thanks a lot!.